# Am I experiencing any effect from black holes gravitational pull?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, gravity, black-holes, estimation

So we know that there is a black hole in the middle of the Milky Way. 
Am I experiencing any effect from the high gravitational pull of the black hole?

If no...then why?

If yes...then how much?

Comment: Fun question, but we do prefer that you put some effort into solving on your own before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distance from you to the center of the galaxy is around 26,000 light years.

The mass of the black hole at the center is estimated to be 4.6 ± 0.7 X 10^6 solar masses.

Newton formulated gravitational force between two bodies (e.g. yours and the black hole's) as

$F = G\frac{m_1m_2}{r^2}$

Where G is the gravitational constant $6.674×10^{−11}$ in units $N⋅m^2⋅kg^{-2}$

From this you can calculate the force you experience due to gravity, using Google to do conversions of distances and masses to meters and kilograms.

It might be interesting to compare this with, for example, the force exerted on you by the international space station passing directly overhead. Or a nearby pebble.